# using codebug with hhvm in docker on macosx

Tags: macos, xdebug, hhvm

I installed hhvm and nginx together in a docker container. The application runs well in the browser. I have turned on xdebug in hopes to use [codebug](http://codebugapp.com/) as a remote server for debugging. 
When i check my network settings my local ip is 192.168.1.11 and I setup codebug to listen on port 9000. In /etc/hhvm/php.ini I have the following directives set

```
; php options
;
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/php5
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
; hhvm specific
hhvm.server.port=9000
hhvm.server.type= fastcgi
hhvm.server.source_root=/var/www/app/public
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
; Xdebug options
xdebug.enable="1"
xdebug.remote_enable="1"
xdebug.idekey="xyz"
xdebug.remote_host="192.168.1.11"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/hhvm.log"
hhvm.debugger.enable_debugger = true
hhvm.debugger.enable_debugger_server = true
```

To make sure codebug was running on that port I ran 
`lsof -i :9000` on my host with the following results:

```
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Codebug 64413 acasanova   13u  IPv4 0x4896ac88e35831db      0t0  TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN)
Codebug 64413 acasanova   14u  IPv6 0x4896ac88dd97dfd3      0t0  TCP *:cslistener (LISTEN)
```

I can run `xdebug_start_code_coverage();
var_dump(xdebug_code_coverage_started());` and the result is  `bool(true)`. I know xdebug is running  and I know codebug is listening. Have I missed any other xdebug directives? Also the remote log does not have any contents after multiple requests to the application.

I added `xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` to the php.ini file and I started to get some activity inside the remote_log file.

```
Log opened at[2014-12-25 08:59:17]
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.1.11:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/leonardo/public/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="1015" idekey="xyz"><engine version=""><![CDATA[xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[HHVM]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://hhvm.com/]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -n max_depth -v 3 -i 2151044
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2151044" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
```

When I add breakpoints in codebug or even xdebug_break(); nothing happens.

Comment: I know basically nothing about xdebug, but is it supposed to run on the same port as the main FastCGI server? That looks really suspicious to me. Have you tried using two different ports?